# Paging library from Architectural components

Tags: android, kotlin, paging

I have following project in Bitbucket : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging
(You need a Api key from https://www.themoviedb.org/ and paste it to local.properties to run the app such as `tmdb_api_key=YOUR_API_KEY`)

In PageKeyedMovieDataSource class I have loadInitial method,

With following line :

```
callback.onResult(items, null, "")
```

I pass `""` for nextPageKey.

And the same story for `loadAfter`method. I pass `""` for adjacentPageKey:

```
callback.onResult(items, "")
```

App works fine but I don't know what is the best approach here. What should I pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just built an app that uses paging with the TMDB, you can see it [here](https://github.com/gilgoldzweig/Movies-demo) the source contains everything you'll need to create a simple app using best practices and clean architecture but if you just want to see the raw code that what I use

Code for returning the result on `loadInitial()`

```
callback.onResult(response.movies, 1, response.totalPages, null, 2)
```

And this code for returning the result on `loadAfter()`

```
callback.onResult(response.movies, params.key + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your repository.